# Does img alt-attribute have equal relevance as normal text in h1?

Tags: seo, image, page-title

There is a question that bothers me for quite some time. I have read  quite a few articles, but gotten no fully satisfying answer.

The Problem: I have an Image with the Company Logo placed at the top of a website.

Now, is

```
<h1><img ... alt="My HP-Title"></h1>
```

in terms of SEO equivalent to

```
<h1>My HP-Title</h1>
```

For long time I used the technique using the logo as `background-image` and `text-indent:-100em` the companies name, but that might be considered as black-hat SEO, so I abandoned that.

On the other hand, even W3C uses a hidden `span` for the title, so perhaps it doesn't matter at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's essentially up to the search engine. But they should be threated the same way, if the browser (or here: the spider) doesn't support images. There's no perfect way to solve the whole question, because in the end you don't know how the search engine will interpret or judge your code. It might ignore the `alt` attribute, but it might as well ignore the empty `span`. Also don't use text alignment to hide text, it might screw up rendering on mobile browsers or browsers interpreting it in a different way (e.g. adding scroll bars to scroll there or resizing the whole page).

The question I'd ask here is: Do you even need the image? Using new standards (CSS2/3, SVG and WOFF) there are lots of possibilities to do most stylized headlines with plain html that won't confuse search engines or let them think you're trying to confuse them.

Comment: first of all i only really care for one searchengine... the googlebot. And afaik google doesn't ignore the alt attributes. And in most cases I have random company logos, so it would be way to much work taking svg or something else. I dont have empty spans and i dont want to hide text. I'm simply wondering, if google rates the alt attribute equal to normal text. Nevertheless thank you for taking your time to answer my question.

Comment: In that case, I'd say use the logo and add the text to the image's `alt` and `title` attributes. Don't add an invisible spawn, as that most likely hurts the weight of the text. Is it equal? Probably noone knows. If it's about having those names as keywords, use the keywords field, use them in the text (if appropriate) and forget about SEO. Not trying to force anything here is most likely the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suspect that visible text is considered more important than the hidden alt text.

As Mario said. If possible avoid using images for text.

There are also some JavaScript libraries that can dynamically replace text with an image of the text.

Comment: I avoid images where ever I can, I just wanted to know if the alt attribute would be equal to normal text. Btw. converting text to images via js makes not much sense to me?!

Comment: Semantically the alt is less prominent than a heading so it would make sense that words in it get ranked lower. The js trick is a way to have the html look like plain text then dynamically replace it with a fancy font version in an image. Not sure if Google can currently detect this or what they consider it as.